# How can I fix column spanning issue in css flex box

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, grid

[check image for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1BAh.png)
I want box three(blue) to come right below box one(red) currently white space inbetween them.
Here, the content height of the box two(gree) is greater than box one hence stretching that extra space.  I need to cover up that empty white space .

I can not use GRID here, as I already used react-bootstrap Row/Col on my entier react site.

https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-david-i2vnht?file=/src/index.js:23-322

I used flexbox and tried using

```
aligh-items:flex-start/flex-end
```

does not work.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.one,
.two,
.three,
.four {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
/* .one,.two,.three,.four, .five,.six{
  flex-grow:1;
  width:33%;
} */
.one {
  background: red;
  padding: 50px;
  order: 0;
  width: 67%;
}
.two {
  background: green;
  order: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 33%;
  height: 30vh;
}
.three {
  background: blue;
  order: 2;
  width: 67%;
  height: 50vh;
}
.four {
  background: tomato;
  order: 3;
  width: 33%;
}
.five {
  background: goldenrod;
  order: 1;
}
.six {
  background: orange;
  order: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="one">ONE</div>
  <div class="three">THREE</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="four">FOUR</div>
  <!-- <div class="five">Five</div> -->
  <!-- <div class="six">Six</div> -->
</div>
```

Comment: This is more naturally a grid really (or CSS columns). Could you explain exactly why you can't use a grid here?

Comment: not better way, but you can use .three { margin-top: -14vh; } to force move up the .tree(blue)

Comment: I can not use Grid because I am using a bootstrap grid system that uses Flex, not Grid. My entire project is built with flexbox, also this is small a part of my react project where other layouts need to be modified if I want to use Grid here.